# R - estimating missing values

Tags: r, data-quality

Let's assume I have a table as such:

```
Date        Sales
09/01/2017  9000
09/02/2017  12000
09/03/2017  0
09/04/2017  11000
09/05/2017  14400
09/06/2017  0
09/07/2017  0
09/08/2017  21000
09/09/2017  15000
09/10/2017  23100
09/11/2017  0
09/12/2017  32000
09/13/2017  8000
```

[image: Here is what the data in the table looks like]

The values in the table are estimated by an R program which I have no access to (it's a black box right now). Now there are a few days with 0 values which tend to creep in due to issues in our ingestion/ETL process. I need to estimate the values for the dates with 0 data.

Our approach is to:

- Draw a line from the date prior to the missing data to the date right
  after the missing data
- Estimate the value for the missing date from the line

Now if there's only one day with missing data between two good days, a straightforward mean would work. If there are two or more consecutive days with missing data, the mean would not work, so I'm trying to formulate a way to go about estimating values for multiple data points.

[image: The intersection of the green and red lines would give the required values]

Would this approach work in R? I'm a total n00b at R so I'm not really sure if this is even feasible.

Comment: Answer below works but you can also accomplish the same thing with the `zoo` package and `na.spline`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fill in the values with linear interpolation using the function `approxfun`.

```
## Your data
df = read.table(text="Date        Sales
09/01/2017  9000
09/02/2017  12000
09/03/2017  0
09/04/2017  11000
09/05/2017  14400
09/06/2017  0
09/07/2017  0
09/08/2017  21000
09/09/2017  15000
09/10/2017  23100
09/11/2017  0
09/12/2017  32000
09/13/2017  8000",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$Date = as.Date(df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")


## Create function for linear interpolation
Interp = approxfun(df[df$Sales > 0, ])

## Use function to fill in interpolated values
Vals = Interp(df$Date[df$Sales == 0])
df$Sales[df$Sales == 0] = Vals
plot(df, type="l")
grid()
```

[image: Interpolated values]

Answer (score 4):

We can also use the `na.interpolation` function from the `imputeTS` package. The default method of `na.interpolation` is linear interpolation, but we can also specify other methods if we want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(imputeTS)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  replace(. == 0, NA) %>%
  mutate(Sales = na.interpolation(Sales))

dt2
         Date Sales
1  09/01/2017  9000
2  09/02/2017 12000
3  09/03/2017 11500
4  09/04/2017 11000
5  09/05/2017 14400
6  09/06/2017 16600
7  09/07/2017 18800
8  09/08/2017 21000
9  09/09/2017 15000
10 09/10/2017 23100
11 09/11/2017 27550
12 09/12/2017 32000
13 09/13/2017  8000
```

**Data**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "Date        Sales
09/01/2017  9000
                 09/02/2017  12000
                 09/03/2017  0
                 09/04/2017  11000
                 09/05/2017  14400
                 09/06/2017  0
                 09/07/2017  0
                 09/08/2017  21000
                 09/09/2017  15000
                 09/10/2017  23100
                 09/11/2017  0
                 09/12/2017  32000
                 09/13/2017  8000",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```